# JavaScript tag type in conditional expression if

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why after clicking the `button`, the condition in `if` is `true`. I would expect that clicking the mentioned button doesn't execute instruction under if:

```js
$('.table tbody tr').click(function (event) {
  if (event.target.type !== 'radio' && event.target.type !== 'button') {
    $(':radio', this).trigger('click');
    $("tr").removeClass("curr_default");
    $(this).addClass("curr_default");
  }
});
```

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    {% for curr in currs %}
    <tr class="{% if curr.default == curr.abbr %}curr_default{% endif %}">
      <th scope="row">{{ loop.index }}
        <span class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="curr_default" />
        </span>
      </th>
      <td>{{ curr.abbr }}</td>
      <td>{{ curr.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <button id="{{ curr.id }}" onClick="get_currID(this.id)" type="button" class="btn p-0 w-auto"
          data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteCurrency">
          <span class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When clicking the `button` you most likely hit the `span` inside the `button` and in the `click` listener the `event.target.type` will be `undefined`.

So either you rework your condition to cover other elements or you could use `pointer-events: none;` (CSS) on the `span` so the click will hit the `button` instead of the `span`.